# Current drop in black box

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design

I’m working wth a closed system (black box), and try to figure out what it consists of. When introducing a current below 400 mA, the current stays constant. When the current exceeds 400mA it drops to 80 mA where it stays constant. What might be hiding inside? Some arrangment of capicators? Or would that stop the entre flow of current?

Comment: How do you source the current? With a constant current source? Or a constant voltge source?

Comment: @jusaca With a constant voltage source. 

The initial goal was to measure the thevening equivalent resistance of the black box. Which proved difficault because of the sudden drop in current

Comment: Might be interesting to know, at which voltage this drop happens.

Comment: @jusaca at 21V, I´m trying to figure out what amount of resistance I have to connect infront of the black box in order to feed it a constant voltage of 5V. But the resistance I need is dependend on the Therevin equi. Resistance, which is varying

Answer (score 4):

Inside, there's a microcontroller and a battery. The microcontroller is programmed to do exactly what you describe. Aside from Monday evenings: Every Monday at 7pm, it morses the text of the French national anthem out.

No, seriously, when trying to reason about what's inside a black box, you need to first describe a model of what it might be.

For beginner's problems, that usually restricts it to *linear* circuits, i.e. ones that are made of resistors, capacitors, inductors, and maybe transformers.

Linearity is clearly not given in your case, so that means that your model would at least include one non-linear element. Maybe it's a single diode, or a single transistor, or maybe it's a combination of a couple thousand of these to actually make the microcontroller I jokingly introduced in the beginning.

You'll need to do more testing:

1. is the system time-invariant? Time-invariant when only excited with harmonic signals?
2. is the system maybe exponential in its in/output behaviour? can you find any other model?
3. is there secondary information on what might be inside? Is it *possible* that it actually contains a power source (e.g. the battery mentioned above), or can we rule that out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the Thevenin Equivalent Circuit of the black box, rather than what is actually inside the box, it is far easier.

**Do not** connect a voltage source to the TEC. Connect known resistors across the TEC terminals and measure the voltage. Now you have a point on the line that defines the relationship between voltage and current. Repeat with a different resistor value. Now you have two points on a line. A bit of algebra will finish it for you.

Comment: Are you assuming that there's a power source inside the box? You haven't said so.

Comment: I was going to ask when OP mentioned that the black box was a thermo-electric cooler. But I think I figured out what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Transistor Good point, I was assuming that there was a power source inside....because the black boxes I use for Thevenin labs do have a battery inside. If the box is entirely passive then this won't work.